Is axiomatic vector space theory with algebraic closed field with fixed characteristic complete?
Hi from my last question I understood that multi-sort first order logic can axiomatic vector space theory.
Furthermore, I can use a predicate symbol to make the multi-sort first order logic to equivalent first order logic.
With that in mind, I would like to further ask if there is a way to know that if vector space theorem $T$ in first order logic (or multi-sort first order logic) is complete?
By complete, I mean for all sentence $\theta$ (which means has no free variable), we have either $T\vdash\theta$ or $T\vdash(\lnot\theta)$
If not, can I make it complete by adding extra axioms?
Thanks so much!

Update: since field it self is incomplete, I would like to ask for algebraic closed field with fixed characteristic!!

Certainly not, since the theory of fields is already not complete: think about the sentence "there exist three distinct scalars."

@noahschweber thanks for the reply. I understand that field is not a complete theorem. But what if I use algebraic closed field with characteristic of $p$?? which is a complete theorem. Then if the theorem of vector space can be complete, or can be complete by adding more axioms ??
